# Question with Joining Database code issue

Tags: r

When I try to join two tables without the KEY, it works perfectly. But when I am providing the Key, it is giving me weird results:

Pls. help me understand what am I missing out.

```
library(gapminder) 
A <- gapminder[gapminder$country=="India" & gapminder$year %in% 1952:1987, 1:4]
B <- gapminder[gapminder$country=="India" & gapminder$year %in% 1977:2007, c(1:3, 5, 6)]
left_join(A, B)
left_join(A, B, by = "country")
```

For without key: I am getting

```
country continent  year lifeExp       pop gdpPercap
  <fct>   <fct>     <int>   <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1 India   Asia       1952    37.4        NA       NA 
2 India   Asia       1957    40.2        NA       NA 
3 India   Asia       1962    43.6        NA       NA 
4 India   Asia       1967    47.2        NA       NA 
5 India   Asia       1972    50.7        NA       NA 
6 India   Asia       1977    54.2 634000000      813.
7 India   Asia       1982    56.6 708000000      856.
8 India   Asia       1987    58.6 788000000      977.
```

But, when I use the Key, it gives me some 56 rows:

```
# A tibble: 56 x 7
   country continent year.x lifeExp year.y    pop
   <fct>   <fct>      <int>   <dbl>  <int>  <dbl>
 1 India   Asia        1952    37.4   1977 6.34e8
 2 India   Asia        1952    37.4   1982 7.08e8
 3 India   Asia        1952    37.4   1987 7.88e8
 4 India   Asia        1952    37.4   1992 8.72e8
 5 India   Asia        1952    37.4   1997 9.59e8
 6 India   Asia        1952    37.4   2002 1.03e9
 7 India   Asia        1952    37.4   2007 1.11e9
 8 India   Asia        1957    40.2   1977 6.34e8
 9 India   Asia        1957    40.2   1982 7.08e8
10 India   Asia        1957    40.2   1987 7.88e8
# ... with 46 more rows, and 1 more variable:
#   gdpPercap <dbl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its called a Cartesian Product / Cross-Join

[Cross Joins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)

Its basically a multiplication of the rows, rather than a straight intersect.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. By mentioning the key how can I make it fetch only those 8 records? With semi_join - I will loose out some columns.

Comment: If I do not provide a key - the function assumes it. Why it is different if I provide one?

Comment: I understood now. The primary keys are country, continent and year. If all these are provided then I get the intended result.